# How to apply css dynamically on webix icon button?

Tags: css, button, webix

I hvae a webix icon button which is disabled in defalut state.
But whenever I select a row of a datatable it should become enable and also a new css class should get applied on it causing its opacity and background color change.

My snippet is https://snippet.webix.com/t3kcujxl

Please help, thanks.

Comment: you could get all the tables, using `querySelectorAll()` then loop through them and then on each table `.addEventListener('click', function(){})` and inside the function give the icon button the class you want

Comment: @A61NN5 Could not understand, could you please elaborate it or show it to me in the snippet itself. My problem is when I am enabling the button then inside the callback the css change is not taking place. Otherwisse, before that, in default state ,the css is working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not change css property of button, just enable it from the click handler

```
onAfterSelect:function() { 
  $$('delete').enable();
}
```

and in css, you can use somethign like next. Here styling of button will differ based on .webix_disabled_view class, which is added to all disabled elements.

```
.webix_disabled_view.opq button{
    background-color: transparent !important; /* Green */
    opacity: 0.4;
}
.opq button{
    background-color: #ac52af; /* red */
    opacity: 1;

}
```

https://snippet.webix.com/z5c09h6z

Comment: Wonderful solution.